# window.history.replaceState is not working in my jquery code

Tags: jquery, pushstate

When photo on my page is clicked it gets full screen, when close button or back button is clicked I want it to be in normal size.

It works fine but back button need to be pressed twice to go to previous page if I close the full screen mode by clicking the close button.

I want to remove state in history when button with class ".btn-close" is clicked but window.history.replaceState is not working.

Here is jquery code

```
$('.photo').click(function(){
     history.pushState('','full-screen');
     $('.gallery').addClass('full-screen');
     // some code here //
});

$('.btn-close').click(function(){
   history.replaceState('','full-screen'); // I want to remove state in history that was pushed previously 
    $('.gallery').removeClass('full-screen');
   // some code here //
});

// Trigger click if back button is pressed
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    $('.btn-close').click();
});
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState), the second parameter of history.replaceState() is currently ignored by most browsers. Also you might want to add a first parameter, even a simple `{foo: 'bar'}` should do.

Answer (score 0):

according to history API sample here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

> Updates the most recent entry on the history stack to have the
> specified data, title, and, if provided, URL.

so `history.replaceState('','full-screen');` doesn't remove the state in history, it replace the last state with the same.

so i have just edited you code like this:

```
$('.photo').click(function(){
     history.pushState('','full-screen');
     $('.gallery').addClass('full-screen');
     // some code here //
});

$('.btn-close').click(function(){
   history.back(); 
    //$('.gallery').removeClass('full-screen');
   // some code here //
});

// Trigger click if back button is pressed
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    //$('.btn-close').click(); remove this line and just do remove full-screen class
    $('.gallery').removeClass('full-screen');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jabbar, can you tell me how to remove last entry from history stack?

Comment: Your second code will not work, it will load previous page.

Comment: @Syed you cant remove last entry for security reason. just can replace the state.

Comment: First code need lots of modifications, i will need to check if specific history state exist in stack.

Comment: np, you can also check this plugin: https://photoswipe.com/ - Browser history API - with details code here: https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/src/js/history.js .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217209/discussion-between-jabbar-and-syed).